# is there something like coo_matrix but for sparse vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, sparse-array

I'm trying to create a sparse vector from a series of arrays where there are some overlapping indexes. For a matrix there's a very [convenient object in scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix) that does exactly this:

```
coo_matrix((data, (i, j)), [shape=(M, N)])
```

So if data happens to have repeated elements (because their i,j indexes are the same), those are summed up in the final sparse matrix. I was wondering if it would be possible to do something similar but for sparse vectors, or do I have just to use this object and pretend it's a 1-column matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you might be able to reproduce a 1d equivalent, it would save a lot of work to just work with a 1 row (or 1 col) sparse matrix.  I am not aware of any sparse vector package for `numpy`.

The `coo` format stores the input arrays exactly as you given them, without the summing.  The summing is done when it is displayed or (otherwise) converted to a `csc` or `csr` format.  And since the `csr` constructor is compiled, it will to that summation faster than anything you could code in Python.

Construct a '1d' sparse coo matrix

```
In [67]: data=[10,11,12,14,15,16]    
In [68]: col=[1,2,1,5,7,5]
In [70]: M=sparse.coo_matrix((data (np.zeros(len(col)),col)),shape=(1,10))
```

Look at its data representation (no summation)

```
In [71]: M.data
Out[71]: array([10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16])
In [72]: M.row
Out[72]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
In [73]: M.col
Out[73]: array([1, 2, 1, 5, 7, 5])
```

look at the array representation (shape `(1,10)`)

```
In [74]: M.A
Out[74]: array([[ 0, 22, 11,  0,  0, 30,  0, 15,  0,  0]])
```

and the csr equivalent.

```
In [75]: M1=M.tocsr()
In [76]: M1.data
Out[76]: array([22, 11, 30, 15])
In [77]: M1.indices
Out[77]: array([1, 2, 5, 7])
In [78]: M1.indptr
Out[78]: array([0, 4])

In [79]: np.nonzero(M.A)
Out[79]: (array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([1, 2, 5, 7]))
```

`nonzero` shows the same pattern:

```
In [80]: M.nonzero()
Out[80]: (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([1, 2, 1, 5, 7, 5]))

In [81]: M.tocsr().nonzero()
Out[81]: (array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([1, 2, 5, 7]))

In [82]: np.nonzero(M.A)
Out[82]: (array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([1, 2, 5, 7]))
```

`M.toarray().flatten()` will give you the `(10,)` 1d array.

Comment: So I followed your example, and the final array is obtained from M.data, correct? This would be the equivalent to a 1-dimensional np.array.

Comment: `M.data` is a 1d array, but it just has the nonzero values (or what you gave it via `coo_matrix`).  You need to include `M.col` to know where the zeros are (or aren't).