# mmap sparse vector in python

Tags: python, numpy, mmap

I'm looking for simple sparse vector implementation that can be mapped into memory, similarly to `numpy.memmap`.

Unfortunately, `numpy` implementation deals only with full vector. Example usage:

```
vec = SparseVector('/tmp/file.dat')  # SparseVector is the class I'm looking for
vec[10] = 10
vec[50] = 21

for key in vec:
    print vec[key]    # 10, 21
```

I foung `scipy` class representing sparse matrix, however 2 dimensions are clumsy to use as I'd need to make matrix with only one row a then use `vec[0,i]`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is `SparseVector` from? Is this something to do with Apache Spark? If so you should tag your question with this information and update the text.

Comment: no, I mean that's the class I'm looking for (don't know name yet), sorry for misunderstanding, I'll make edit asap

Answer (score 0):

Someone else was just asking about 1d sparse vectors, only they wanted to take advantage of the `scipy.sparse` method of handling duplicate indices.

[is there something like coo_matrix but for sparse vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565798/is-there-something-like-coo-matrix-but-for-sparse-vectors)

As shown there, a `coo_matrix` actually consists of 3 `numpy` arrays, `data`, `row`, `col`.  Other formats rearrange the values in other ways, `lil` for example has 2 nested lists, one for the data, another for the coordinates. `dok` is a regular dictionary, with `(i,j)` tuples as keys.

In theory then a sparse vector will require 2 arrays.  Or as your example shows it could be a simple dictionary.

So you could implement a mmap sparse vector by using two mmap arrays.  As far as I know there isn't a mmap version of the `scipy sparse` matrices, though it's not something I've looked for.

But what functionality do you want?  What dimension?  So large that a dense version would not fit in regular memory?  Are you doing math with it?  Or just data lookup?